# Can onSuccess/onFailure replace setHandler of CompositeFuture in vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

I thought they were the same, but sometime, both of `onSuccess` and `onFailure` might not be entered, that's very strange, does anyone know that? Thank you!

```java
CompositeFuture.all(future1(), future2(), future3())
                .setHandler(ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                    } else {}
                });
```

```java
CompositeFuture.all(future1(), future2(), future3())
                .onSuccess(result -> {
                })
                .onFailure(e -> {
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been reported and will be fixed in 3.8.5 (due in the next couple weeks).

https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/3242